# Container's stdout to another container

Tags: docker, logging

I have a container with a software running on it, displaying some output to stdout of this container.
I would like this output to be redirected to another container, to be displayed on a webpage for example.
Is it possible ?

Comment: what did you try so far? How about a volume shared by both containers, one writes to a file, while the other one reads from it ?

Comment: I thought about writing stdout to a file then with rsyslog send it to a rsyslog server, but I thought it was way too complicated.
I'll see what I can do with a shared volume, thanks

Comment: one more thing: on *nix system it could be a named pipe (to avoid data accumulation)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how I would implement this ?